# Why my JFrame is not appearing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Can anyone explain me or suggest a solution to the following problem? I have two projects in eclipse workspace, and in the `projectA` this class runs just fine:

```
public class Example extends JFrame {


public Example() {
       setTitle("Simple example");
       setSize(300, 200);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Example ex = new Example();
       ex.setVisible(true);
    }
```

}

In projectB, the same code is giving me the following error:

```
2014-05-30 16:18:44.885 java[26656:507] Cocoa AWT: Running on AppKit thread 0 when not expected. (
    0   liblwawt.dylib                      0x000000010fff729e Java_sun_java2d_opengl_CGLLayer_nativeCreateLayer + 119
    1   ???                                 0x000000010c0fbf90 0x0 + 4497325968
)
2014-05-30 16:18:44.886 java[26656:507]     Please file a bug report at http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT with this message and a reproducible test case.
2014-05-30 16:18:44.887 java[26656:507] Cocoa AWT: Running on AppKit thread 0 when not expected. (
    0   liblwawt.dylib                      0x000000011000014c Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_CPlatformView_nativeCreateView + 169
    1   ???                                 0x000000010c0fbf90 0x0 + 4497325968
    2   ???                                 0x000000010c0f0275 0x0 + 4497277557
    3   ???                                 0x000000010c0f0158 0x0 + 4497277272
)
2014-05-30 16:18:44.887 java[26656:507]     Please file a bug report at http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT with this message and a reproducible test case.
2014-05-30 16:18:44.888 java[26656:507] Cocoa AWT: Running on AppKit thread 0 when not expected. (
    0   liblwawt.dylib                      0x00000001100004e4 Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_CPlatformWindow_nativeCreateNSWindow + 188
    1   ???                                 0x000000010c0fbf90 0x0 + 4497325968
    2   ???                                 0x000000010c0f0275 0x0 + 4497277557
)
2014-05-30 16:18:44.889 java[26656:507]     Please file a bug report at http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT with this message and a reproducible test case.
2014-05-30 16:18:44.897 java[26656:507] Cocoa AWT: Running on AppKit thread 0 when not expected. (
    0   liblwawt.dylib                      0x0000000110005c28 Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_CPlatformComponent_nativeCreateComponent + 119
    1   ???                                 0x000000010c0fbf90 0x0 + 4497325968
)
2014-05-30 16:18:44.897 java[26656:507]     Please file a bug report at http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT with this message and a reproducible test case.
2014-05-30 16:18:44.898 java[26656:507] Cocoa AWT: Running on AppKit thread 0 when not expected. (
    0   liblwawt.dylib                      0x00000001100057dd Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_CPlatformWindow_nativeSetNSWindowTitle + 60
    1   ???                                 0x000000010c0fbf90 0x0 + 4497325968
    2   ???                                 0x000000010c0f0158 0x0 + 4497277272
)
2014-05-30 16:18:44.899 java[26656:507]     Please file a bug report at http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT with this message and a reproducible test case.
2014-05-30 16:18:44.899 java[26656:507] Cocoa AWT: Running on AppKit thread 0 when not expected. (
    0   liblwawt.dylib                      0x000000011000504e Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_CPlatformWindow_nativeSetNSWindowStyleBits + 69
    1   ???                                 0x000000010c0fbf90 0x0 + 4497325968
)
2014-05-30 16:18:44.899 java[26656:507]     Please file a bug report at http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT with this message and a reproducible test case.
2014-05-30 16:18:44.900 java[26656:507] Cocoa AWT: Running on AppKit thread 0 when not expected. (
    0   liblwawt.dylib                      0x0000000110004a1f Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_CPlatformWindow_nativeSetNSWindowMinMax + 79
    1   ???                                 0x000000010c0fbf90 0x0 + 4497325968
)
2014-05-30 16:18:44.900 java[26656:507]     Please file a bug report at http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT with this message and a reproducible test case.
2014-05-30 16:18:44.900 java[26656:507] Cocoa AWT: Running on AppKit thread 0 when not expected. (
    0   liblwawt.dylib                      0x00000001100058e7 Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_CPlatformWindow_nativeGetNSWindowInsets + 72
    1   ???                                 0x000000010c0fbf90 0x0 + 4497325968
    2   ???                                 0x000000010c0f0333 0x0 + 4497277747
    3   ???                                 0x000000010c0f09e1 0x0 + 4497279457
)
2014-05-30 16:18:44.901 java[26656:507]     Please file a bug report at http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT with this message and a reproducible test case.
2014-05-30 16:18:44.911 java[26656:507] Cocoa AWT: Running on AppKit thread 0 when not expected. (
    0   liblwawt.dylib                      0x0000000110004390 Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_CPlatformWindow_nativeSetNSWindowMinimizedIcon + 64
    1   ???                                 0x000000010c0fbf90 0x0 + 4497325968
)
2014-05-30 16:18:44.912 java[26656:507]     Please file a bug report at http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT with this message and a reproducible test case.
2014-05-30 16:18:44.913 java[26656:507] Cocoa AWT: Running on AppKit thread 0 when not expected. (
    0   liblwawt.dylib                      0x0000000110004159 Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_CPlatformWindow_nativeSynthesizeMouseEnteredExitedEvents + 59
    1   ???                                 0x000000010c0fbf90 0x0 + 4497325968
)
2014-05-30 16:18:44.913 java[26656:507]     Please file a bug report at http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT with this message and a reproducible test case.
2014-05-30 16:18:44.914 java[26656:507] Cocoa AWT: Running on AppKit thread 0 when not expected. (
    0   liblwawt.dylib                      0x0000000110006e20 Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_CCursorManager_nativeGetCursorPosition + 66
    1   ???                                 0x000000010c0fbf90 0x0 + 4497325968
)
2014-05-30 16:18:44.914 java[26656:507]     Please file a bug report at http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT with this message and a reproducible test case.
2014-05-30 16:18:44.914 java[26656:507] Cocoa AWT: Running on AppKit thread 0 when not expected. (
    0   liblwawt.dylib                      0x000000011000504e Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_CPlatformWindow_nativeSetNSWindowStyleBits + 69
    1   ???                                 0x000000010c0fbf90 0x0 + 4497325968
    2   ???                                 0x000000010c0f0158 0x0 + 4497277272
    3   ???                                 0x000000010c0f0158 0x0 + 4497277272
)
2014-05-30 16:18:44.915 java[26656:507]     Please file a bug report at http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT with this message and a reproducible test case.
```

In that `projectB` I have a lot of other classes, all with correct Java code, and some of them with mains which runs just fine. But, also, in `projectB`, if I try to run code which makes some really basic swing window within the existing main (which was running just fine without  swing code) it will run the application, but my JFrame won't appear.

Comment: one another recommendation, super("Simple example"); instead of        setTitle("Simple example");

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Example extends JFrame {

    public Example() {
       this.setTitle("Simple example");
       this.setSize(300, 200);
       this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Example ex = new Example();
       ex.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

What we're doing here is extending JFrame. Example IS-A subclass of JFrame and now inherits all of its functionality. We can then use the setter methods defined in JFrame and its superclasses in our constructor method (Example()), by using 'this' to **explicitly** refer to the current instance of Example at hand.

See here for information on ['this'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Comment: class keyword is already written at the beginning of the code

Comment: He has a configuration problem in the projectB, not a code problem. (Although he is missing `invokeLater` in the main)